# JavaFX migrate StringProperty [value: ""] to simple String

Tags: java, javafx

How I can convert StringProperty to String? I need only text value.
But my function is show to me "StringProperty [value: bbbbbb]"
I know about JavaFX specific accessor syntax and accessors. But I could not understand how to put that correctly.

```
public class TestDelete {

private static StringProperty myTestValue = new SimpleStringProperty();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setText();
}

private static void setText() {
    TestDelete testDelete = new TestDelete();
    String myText = "aaaaa bbbbbb";
    myTestValue = new SimpleStringProperty(myText.replaceAll(".* ", ""));
    System.out.println(myTestValue);
}

public void getmyTestValue() {
    myTestValue.get();
}

public void setmyTestValue(String newVal) {
    myTestValue.set(newVal);
}

public StringProperty myTestValueProperty() {
    return myTestValue;
}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.println(myTestValue.get())` ????

Comment: Thank you. I will try to cast that to String,

Comment: You don't need to cast it. `StringProperty.get()` already returns a `String`.

Comment: time to work through a tutorial on javafx basics, namely properties ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple string property works as

```
public class NewBean {
SimpleStringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty();
SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

public NewBean(){
    
}

public String getId() {
    return id.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id.set(id);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
}
```